# Discrete math with probability.

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

```
Suppose you play the venerable game rock-paper-scissors. If you pick paper
and your opponent chooses arbitrarily, what is the probability that you will
win? If each of you pick arbitrarily, what is the probability that you will
win?
```

I'm quite confident that the `P(win with rock)` is `rock/rock+scissor+paper` which comes out to be 1/3

but I'm not so sure about the 2nd part of the question, Im thinking its `rock or scissor or paper/rock+scissor+paper` which comes out to the same answer but that doesnt seem correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probability that you choose paper is $1/3$ and you winning with paper is $1/3$. This goes for other options also as all options have $1$ strength, $1$ weakness and $1$ twin. Hence,

$$P=\frac 1 3\times\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3\times\frac 1 3+\frac 1 3\times\frac 1 3=\frac 1 3$$